# How do I search for two strings on the same line in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Mainly I want to search for all lines that contain XXX and YYY on the same line in Eclipse.

What would be the correct search expression for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This regex should comply with your request:

```
(XXX.*YYY|YYY.*XXX)
```

Used under File Search, checking Regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use XXX*YYY in file search option.
This will mean that any characters can come in between XXX and YYY.